# localising objects in Tensorflow using inception V3

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, tensorflow, deep-learning

I have seen [this](http://silverpond.com.au/2016/10/24/pedestrian-detection-using-tensorflow-and-inception.html) blog post which describes how you can localise an object in an image using Google's image classification model Inception V3.

> "We can interpret the 8x8x2048 representation as a grid of features,
>   breaking the image down into 8 horizontal and 8 vertical grid
>   squares."

Can anyone explain how I can access the 8x8x2048 layer of Inception in python? and then use a 1x1 convolution to map each one of these vectors to a class label?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [inception model in tensorflow's repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_model.py) calls the [`inception.slim.inception_v3`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py#L52) function where you need to modify the network [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py#L282) to add one more layer for the 1x1 convolution.

The change would be very small, you can just follow the way it constructs other layers. To be simple, the layer would be like:

```
net = ops.conv2d(net, 2048, [1, 1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your informative answer. The links were a big help!

If I add "Print 'Here'" to [line 78 of the slim inception model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/slim/inception_model.py#L78) nothing happens when I run [this code](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/wolffg/541c97a74dfc0d77c4b8fd2a946a5b41/raw/578853dd26180dbf5bfc66eb40fdd13fb3aba4d6/TensorFlow%2520codelab), provided by Google.

In the provided Google code, is it not running the slim inception model? Is it possible to tell it to use the slim model?

Thanks!

Comment: The code you pointed to me is not using the slim function, you can take a look at how the slim function is used: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_model.py#L81

Comment: You code read the graph from "/tf_files/retrained_graph.pb". I guess this is not what you intended to do. You have to build your own graph.

Answer (score 0):

I have found you can get the 8x8x2048

```
    with tf.Session(config=config) as sess:
        tensor = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('mixed_10/join:0')
        for image_to_test in os.listdir(directory):
            image = os.path.join(directory, image_to_test)
            with tf.gfile.FastGFile(image, 'rb') as f:
                image_data = f.read()
                decoded={'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data}
                predictions = sess.run(tensor, decoded)
```

predictions now has the 8x8x2048

however I havent figured out how to get a class from the "2048" values

I am trying

```
import tensorflow.contrib.slim as slim

predictions = sess.run(tensor, decoded)
ppp= slim.conv2d(predictions,2048,[1,1])
x=tf.unstack(ppp)
```

but this gives back a tensor

Tensor("Conv/Relu:0", shape=(1, 8, 8, 2048), dtype=float32, device=/device:CPU:0)

[<tf.Tensor 'unstack:0' shape=(8, 8, 2048) dtype=float32>]